# video play after close the popup from window

Tags: javascript, html, css, video, popup

when i m open my website then the popup will open this popup in the body

index.php
`

```
<div id="popUpDiv" style="display:none; margin:-450px -170px;">
    <a href="#" id="playvideo" onClick="popup('popUpDiv')"><img src="images/cro.png" height="30" width="30" style=" margin-left:173px; margin-top:-16px; border:none;"/></a>
</div>


      <video id="playvideo" controls autoplay style="margin-top: 24px; margin-bottom: -26px;">
```

and i have a video on my website its a autoplay video i want when i close the popup then the video play

anyone help me in this 
thanks in advance

Comment: wheres your JavaScript?

Answer (score 1):

Try this if you're using Jquery dialog:

```
$("#popUpDiv").dialog({
closeOnEscape: true,
buttons:
{
    "ok": function () {
      $(this).dialog("close");
      $('#playvideo')[0].play();
}
```

Comment: Based on what I have understood I have provided you the answer..If not ask your question with a clear view with more information.

Comment: dear bro i want when i closed the popup when the video play